# How to pass variables in where clause when it contains both in_clause and single value conditions in python/cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, list, where-clause

I am stuck at below part of code of python involving cx_Oracle.
I am trying to do a update on table like below:-

update table
set column3 = 'x'
where column1 in (1,2,3) and column2 = 4

I am able to do it with one column pass as list only:-

Example:-

in_clause_list = [1,2,3]

in_clause = ', '.join([':i%d' % x for x in xrange(len(in_clause_list))])

statement = "update table set column3 = x where column1 in (%s)"

cursor.execute(statement %in_clause, in_clause_list)

with this I am able to proceed.

And I am able to do below also:-

where_clause_tuple = (1,4)

statement = "update table set column3 = x where column1  = :column1 and column2 = :column2"

cursor.execute(statement , where_clause_tuple)

But stuck with below for days:-

update table
set column3 = x
where column1 in (1,2,3) and column2 = 4

How can I pass values both in "in_clause" variables and direct single value where clause conditions.
In all I am not able to bind variables.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a simple concatenation approach like this:

```
in_clause_list = [1,2,3]
in_clause = "('{0}')".format("','".join(map(str, in_clause_list)))
where_clause_tuple = (1,4)
statement = "update table set column3 = x where column1 in " + in_clause 
+ " and column2 =  " + str(where_clause_tuple[1])
cursor.execute(statement)
```